# Android GridView Background color on Selection

Tags: android, gridview

I have created a GridView that displays various Bitmaps . I want that when a user selects selects a cell its back ground color changes. This is what i am doing. My ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter has the following lines of code in it the getView function

```
if(videoObjects.get(position).isSelected)
{
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else
{
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

My GridView has a OnItemClickListener that has the following code in onItemClick.

```
   userVideos.get(postion).isSelected=!userVideos.get(postion).isSelected;
    videoBitmapsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should toggle the boolean variable and then i redraw the adapter. But the selection does not work.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. This works fine, i had made a programming mistake in drawing the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to use a selector as background with 2 states:

```
<selector>
 <item state_selected="true" drawable="yourbg" />
 <item state_selected="false" drawable="otherbg" />
</selector>
```

Then in your

```
 onItemClick(View v, ViewGroup parent, int position){
  if (this.previousSelectedView != null) this.previousSelectedView.setSelected(false);
  v.setSelected(true);
 }
```

That way, there is no need to invalidate the whole gridview. You'll have to keep a reference to the currently selected griditem, so you can deselect it when a different item is clicked.

*(This code is not tested)*

Comment: also add `this.previousSelectedView = v` after `v.setSelected(true);`